# Vim disable the display of accents in latex file

Tags: vim, latex

I have a problem when writing with vim in a .tex file.

When I type, for example :

```
\`e
```

I automatically get :

```
è
```

Which I would like to disable, because it is really annoying when writing, the cursor is then not well placed because it reads \'e and not è while showing è.

I've only found solutions to show the accents and not disable them.
I know one of the solutions could be to set the file as plain text but I suppose that the syntax colour wouldn't be as enhanced.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, what you are seeing, is the conceal feature of Vim, of which you can read about at `:h new-conceal`

If you don't want the concealing, you can disable it  altogether using:
`:set conceallevel=0`

You can further finetune when to conceal characters in the help at
`:h g:ft-tex-syntax` or more specifically `:h g:tex_conceal`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able disable to it with the help of this [forum](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Disable-the-conceal-feature-td4476727.html) So adding `set cole=0` and `au FileType * setl cole=0` to my vimrc solved my problem. Thank you again :)